# ASP.net insert html encoded code into page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-encode

I have a `dim` which contains `html encoded` code, which is stored in DB.

**How can I insert the code into asp.net page?**
I would like to perform the action in code behind ( `VB.net / C#` ).

What control/method should I use. Please note I want the **code to be rendered by the browsers** – not just displayed.

Comment: are you looking for HttpUtility.HtmlDecode and HttpUtility.HtmlEncode methods?
what exactly is stored in your DB?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming web forms, you can use a [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz4949ks.aspx) control on your web page and set its [`Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode%28d=lightweight%29.aspx) property to `PassThrough`.

`PassThrough` meaning

> The contents of the control are not modified.

as opposed to the default `Transform`

> The contents of the control are converted to an HTML-encoded string.

Example aspx:

```html
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Mode="PassThrough" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Code-behind:

```vb
Me.Literal1.Text = "<p>I'm a paragraph.</p>"
```

Comment: I edited the answer to include the definition of PassThrough and Transform. Check out the linked msdn documentation, there are even more details and examples.